# Trouble regarding Booking Tickets

Tags: india, bookings, indian-railways, refunds

I was booking a ticket on the Coromondal Express to travel from Howrah to Chennai through Internet banking.

While my account has been debited and a transaction ID has been provided, when I accessed the booking section of IRCTC to find my tickets, it says the ticket has not been booked and it is again asking for payment.

I called up the customer care of IRCTC but they did not respond. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was quite common earlier, the number of such occurrences has decreased now. Due to the large volume of transactions that irctc website caters to, some of the transactions fail.
In your case, the communication between the bank website and irctc must have timed out. You will receive a refund for this. However, the services charges will be deducted.
It is best to book another ticket. In future, please try to book a ticket again.
More details are present here: https://www.services.irctc.co.in/beta_htmls/Alerts_mone_debited.html

Comment: when will I get the refund ?

Comment: Yes, you will. You can check for failed transactions under [My Transactions] -> [Failed transactions] menu present below the irctc logo after you log in. Added the FAQ page link in my answer above.

Comment: It is only written under "My transaction" as "failed".No options as you provided in the link are provided there. what to do? please help

Comment: Don't worry. The money will be refunded. I have faced it several times before.

Comment: all right I will wait .thanks can u give me any suggestion on how many days I will have to wait

Comment: You will receive the refund in 3 - 4 days